# "Yes." posts: worm/virus or spam?

Tags: support, users, spam

I'm seeing more than one post like this:

```
 __ __           
|  |  |___ ___   
|_   _| -_|_ -|_ 
  |_| |___|___|_|
```

Are these hijacked users or something?

Clarification: I know it's ascii art, but I saw it posted twice from more than one user within minutes of each other.  Obviously it could be the same user with more than one account, but I thought I'd check and point it out.

Ex:

[Is this valid Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110014/is-this-valid-java/3113396#3113396)

I found the first one I saw:

[Side-effect free methods in the Java Standard Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113247/side-effect-free-methods-in-the-java-standard-library/3113295#3113295)

Comment: Could be a co-worker messing about with his/her account, as only the most recent activity has stuff like that. I think a mod should take a look at this.

Comment: Unless it's someone going for the Peer Pressure badge ;)

Comment: Just flag the post as spam and move on.

Comment: There's another on SU http://superuser.com/questions/37392/usb-microphone-too-quiet/156424#156424

Comment: @ChrisF same user from one of the ones I posted, so maybe it's just someone spamming.  Stackoverflow, like facebook, would be a popular target for a "social" virus, however.

Comment: @Software: except that it is not spam

Comment: @Kop: It most certainly is; it's a post which simply adds noise and provides no benefit whatsoever.

Comment: @Software: that's not the definition of spam. Spam is unsolicited bulk advertisement. Check wikipedia :O Also keep in mind that if enough people flag it as "spam" the user loses 100 or 200 reputation (I don't remember); so it's not something that should be done lightly or with very broad definitions of spam, at least IMO.

Answer (score 2):

There's a deleted answer by the same author that looks something like this:

> ---
>
> |  |  |**_** 
>   |   *| -*|_ -|_ 
>     |*| |*|*|*|

Looks like it took him a couple of attempts to get right.

Comment: They're both Java questions... my guess is that I__ saw mcandre's post, thought it was funny, and tried to copy/paste it, but took a little while to get the spacing right.

Comment: @Randolpho very possible.

Comment: Somebody just let the air out of that one.

Answer (score 1):

Did you see his [question:answer ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/117700/i)?

That's obviously an account fishing for easy rep

Comment: I don't know -- there are identical posts from other users.  They certainly don't garner rep when they get downvoted 4+ times like the other one I saw.

Comment: Do you have any other links? @jon

Comment: I couldn't locate the first one I saw, only noticed it when I saw the second one.

Comment: Wow.  With a 99% accept rate, he's gotten nearly 3/4 of his rep from just *accepting answers*.

Comment: That's disgusting.  Perhaps it's time to put a rate limit on how many +2 bonuses one account can receive.

Answer (score 0):

It's just an old-fashioned piece of [ASCII art](http://www.google.com/search?q=ascii+art&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-US&ie=utf8&oe=utf8&rlz=).

Comment: Yes, but I've seen it posted from more than one user within minutes of each other.

Answer (score 0):

```
 _____      _         _ _      _   _   _     _      _ _   _     
|     |   _| |___ ___| | |_   | |_| |_|_|___| |_   |_| |_| |___ 
|-   -|  | . | . |   |_|  _|  |  _|   | |   | '_|  | |  _|_|_ -|
|_____|  |___|___|_|_| |_|    |_| |_|_|_|_|_|_,_|  |_|_|   |___|

 _ _ _ ___ ___ _____   
| | | | . |  _|     |_ 
|_____|___|_| |_|_|_|_|
```

But the user [does have spam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365307/what-determines-the-return-value-of-path-gettemppath) (see the 5th comment of the question).

Comment: Maybe I'll inspire someone to write one with my post.  Has it been done before?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985540/code-golf-banner-generation

Comment: you seem to have dropped this -> `a`

Comment: You don't think it's warm?  What's warm?