# It's my birthday, but only Data Explorer recognizes it

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Note to Robert Cartaino: don't look at your Data Explorer profile on your birthday. :)

Meta:

[image]

Stack Overflow:

[image]

Data Explorer:

[image]

---

**UPDATE:** The systems are now showing the correct age. I'm assuming that Jeff made it so that it rolls over at 12:00, as that would be the average time you were born on your birth date. Which is true for everyone, and yet true for no one, especially in practice.

Comment: (Waiting for Jeff to put `[status-bydesign]`, claiming that everyone was born at 23:59:59 on their day of birth.)

Comment: If Data Explorer makes you a year older than the others, shouldn't your title read: "...Data Explorer *hates* me"?

Comment: @Robert: I'm in the minority, I guess, as I don't really care about my age in absolute terms (maybe I'm too young for that ;) ); but I would like the system to show the *correct* age (which is 27, in case that wasn't clear).

Comment: @Jon Seigel: In about 3 years, you'll come back and vote up my comment <grin>.

Comment: Hey, its my birthday too: http://odata.stackexchange.com/users/1 , http://stackoverflow.com/users/17174/sam-saffron :)

Comment: You know the correct behavior would be to ask you for your GMT birth minute, then we could really show your age properly... <me>scratching my head</me> is it really my birthday in the USA now or not ? very confused

Comment: May be system should allow adding our birthday as unix epoch date?

Comment: @waffles: Happy birthday! It's actually not quite the 25th here (~1.5 hours to go), but it is on SOST (Stack Overflow Standard Time).

Comment: @S.Mark: with microsecond resolution :-P

Comment: Its always your birthday in Iceland.

Comment: Happy birthday! :)

Comment: Happy Birthday Jon Seigel, and waffles

Comment: Happy birthday~

Comment: Isn't this "too localized"? It only matters to *one* user, *one* day a year.

Comment: @devinb - are you suggesting that only one user has a birthday?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The age field rolls over at noon (Stack Overflow Standard Time) on your birthday.

Since this will only annoy me once/year, I'll let it go as `[status-bydesign]`.

Also, I request that I be allowed to sleep in until noon on my birthday no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine the problem is that none of the sites know what *time* you were born, they only know the *day*. So, everyone was born at 00:00:00. The inconsistency between sites would almost certainly reflect the differing timezones of the respective servers.

Comment: No, I took the screenshots right after GMT rolled over on SO. Now that it's gone past 12:00, it's showing the correct age, so possibly Jeff set it up to "an average time" on the day of birth.